# Facebook connect without Javascript in WiFi Hotspot

Tags: authentication, facebook

I am going to integrate the Facebook login access on my WiFi hotspot portal. Basically I would like the user to log on my portal using its Facebook credentials, in order to access the Internet via Hotspot.
The classical integration using connect-js via Javascript cannot work, since unauthenticated users cannot reach the Internet, and in this condition the browser cannot connect to Facebook.com.
Please, I would like to understand if there is a way, from my PHP portal, to send an HTTP post request to Facebook.com containing the users credentials. I just have made a test, but I have received the following response "For your security, never enter your Facebook password on sites not located on Facebook.com".
Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you been able to make any progress on this?

Comment: anything done yet trying it with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [manually-build-a-login-flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/#login) (relevant facebook documentation)

The below snippet is the crux of it however

```
https://www.facebook.com/v3.0/dialog/oauth?
    client_id={app-id}
    &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
    &state={state-param}
```